# replace class name with javascript

Tags: javascript

I need help finding an element with a specific class name and then replace it with a new class name. Here is the code I came up with. I get no results. The class name does not change, and there are no errors in the console.

**Updated Code**:

```
var classMatches = document.querySelectorAll(".crux.attachFlash");
for (var i = 0; i < classMatches.length; i++) {
    classMatches[i].className = " ";
}
```

Comment: You're looping but never using the `i` to actually access an individual element of the collection.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Because you need to amend the class-name of the matched element, not the array of elements:

```
var classMatches = document.querySelectorAll(".crux.attachFlash");
for (var i = 0; i < classMatches.length; i++) {
    classMatches[i].className = " ";
}
```

You forgot the `[i]` index, so you were trying to set the `className` for whole array (Which, as you've found, does not work).

Comment: Ah! thank you so much that clears it up :) Oh if I could ask about one more thing. If i wanted to use `getElementsByClassName` instead of `querySelectorAll` could you show me how?

Comment: As far as I'm aware there's no difference; just substitute `getElementsByClassName()` for `querySelectorAll()`.